# Why is this property not able to be resolved, but accessible if I go via a dynamic cast?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, casting, compiler-errors, outlook-addin

My method takes a [`Outlook.MailItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx) as a parameter. Upon inspecting the MailItem object and reading the documentation, I noticed it had a property named [`Sender`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.sender.aspx) which returns an [`AddressEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.aspx).
When I wanted to use this property, I got the following error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'Sender'`, and Sender got highlighted in red. Trying to build and ignoring the highlighting results in:

> 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem' does not contain a definition for 'Sender' and no extension method 'Sender' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Weird, the documentation says the property exist and when I debug I can even inspect the value. (I have to use VS2010 on this old project so the debugging inspection isn't great with all the `System.__ComObject`'s, but I can inspect the value of `Sender`, so it exists.)

However when I cast the `MailItem` to `dynamic`, I can access the Sender as follows without any problems:

```
var sender = (AddressEntry)((dynamic)mailItem).Sender;
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm currently blaming it on VS2010 for lack of a better explanation.

Comment: IIRC `dynamic` was added to the language in part to allow `IDispatch` objects like that one to be treated as if they were normal C# class instances.

Comment: For what it's worth (maybe nothing) I can confirm it works just fine in VS 2012 and 2014... `mailItem.Sender`. Have you included the correct namespace? `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, looking at the documentation I don't see `AddressEntry` interface have a property of `Sender`, but `MailItem` does. Perhaps you meant to cast it as `MailItem`?

Comment: @musefan yep, tried with the full namespace as well, no go. Thanks for trying it in newer visual studio's!

@EdPlunkett haven't heard from the `IDispatch` objects you mention, but they sound scary, could you tell me more about them?

@12seconds, The `MailItem.Sender` property is of type `AddressEntry`, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @ThomasMulder: Actually, I already had a Outlook Addin project open in 2014 that I created when using 2012... hehe

Comment: @ThomasMulder Yes, `MailItem.Sender` returns type `AddressEntry`, so wouldn't it just be `var sender = ((MailItem)(mailItem)).Sender;` ?

Comment: `IDispatch` is the mechanism that COM objects written in C or C++ use to do what would be "reflection" in C#. That is, you have a string that names a method of an object; `IDispatch` is an interface that allows you to ask the object "do you have a method of this name? What are its parameters?  Please invoke it with these arguments..." and so on. It's how COM objects do late bound dispatch; hence the name. In C#, `dynamic` knows about `IDispatch` and will use it to call methods on COM objects if the COM object supports the interface.

Comment: oddly Ive used Mailitem.SenderEmailAddresss a bunch of times and never had to recast the item from mailitem..

Comment: @12seconds, mailitem is already a `MailItem`, so casting it to that doesn't help, I still get the error.

Comment: @BugFinder `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress` is available, `MailItem.Sender` isn't...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all thanks to everyone who took the time to think along.

Turns out that `MailItem` is an interface (so *THAT*'s why youput an  `I` in front of your interface name, like `IMailItem`), and I had an older version of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;` in my solution. Once I updated this (and the `Office` reference on which it depends) to a newer version, I could access the `MailItem.Sender`.

So it was in the documentation for a newer version... My bad!